# Using JSFiddle with React-based external library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsfiddle

How do I go about using an external library with JSFiddle?

**What I have tried:**

In the left bar I have tried adding `react-textfit`. I also tried using `unpkg.com/react-textfit` as well.

Then in the code section, I add the following:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>
      <TextFit>Hello</TextFit>
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Expected an identifier and instead saw '<'
```

How do I properly use a React library in JSFiddle?

**My JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/1ao36059/1/

Comment: you can use stackblitz/codesandbox if using JSFiddle only isn't a requirement